# Sampling from the inverse wishart distribution in R

Tags: r, inverse

I am reading the following in the book "Bayesian Data Analysis"

[image]

In the book, the matrix S is defined as follows:

[image]

For the sake of the question, let's assume that I have S calculated. I would like to be able to sample from the distribution of Sigma|y, i.e., the inverse wishart distribution. I am using the `MCMCpack` package in `R` to do so and what I can't quite understand is whether the function expects me to pass it S or the inverse of S, i.e.,

```
library(MCMCpack)
S <- matrix(c(1,.3,.3,1),2,2)

## Use S?
riwish(4, S)

## or use S^{-1}
riwish(4, solve(S))
```

It is not clear to me from the documentation which one is expected.

Comment: Looking at the source code of `riwish` helps, I think ...

Comment: @BenBolker my apologies as I am a little dense. So the source code is the following: `return(solve(rwish(v, solve(S))))` and I know there is a fact about the Wishart distribution having the inverse scale matrix of the inverse wishart distribution, but I'm not sure how to put that together.

Comment: Sorry. Can you clarify what `S` is?  (i.e., how it is defined in the immediately preceding section of BDA)? Is it the empirical covariance matrix?

Comment: @BenBolker I added a screen shot in my question, but S is the is close to the empirical covariance matrix but not exactly (it's `cov(Y) * (nrow(Y) - 1)`

Comment: OK, thanks ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way to figure this out is to think carefully about whether each object/variable is on the *variance* scale or the *precision* (inverse-variance) scale. `?riwish` says:

> The mean of an inverse Wishart random variable with ‘v’ degrees of freedom and scale matrix ‘S’ is (v-p-1)^{-1} S.

We want the final answer (the posterior distribution of the covariance matrix) to be on the variance scale. If the mean of the random variable is is proportional to `S`, that must mean that `S` *as input to `riwish`* should also be on the covariance scale.

We can also confirm by brute force that using `S` gives us a sensible value (since the Jeffreys prior is weakly informative we should get a mean approximately equal to `S`):

```r
S <- matrix(c(1,.3,.3,1),2,2)
set.seed(101)
replicate(10000, MCMCpack::riwish(4, S)) |> apply(c(1,2), mean)

         [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 1.009743 0.2656540
[2,] 0.265654 0.9415342
```

```r
Sinv <- solve(S)
replicate(10000, MCMCpack::riwish(4, Sinv)) |> apply(c(1,2), mean)

           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  1.0273954 -0.3092717
[2,] -0.3092717  1.0217894
```

Comment: Hah! I was literally doing the same thing as you mentioned it! I.e., E <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

N <- 10000
for(i in 1:N){
  E <- E + MCMCpack::riwish(33, S)
}

E/N

1 / (33 - 2 - 1) * S